# Rails mixing templating languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, mustache

I'm working with a large project where the templates are written in erb. We're getting more and more into client side rendering of parts of the project and we have lots of exact duplicates in mustache of our erb templates.

I'd like to change the erb templates that are replicated in mustache to mustache and print the js templates out from those templates.

I haven't been able to figure out how to mix templating languages in rails though, is this possible? I'd rather not rewrite all the erb templates in mustache.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Isotope](http://devign.me/isotope-hybrid-ruby-on-rails-template-engine-for-client-side-and-server-side/) could be useful for you? I never tried it though.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I fear you'd have no direct solution...

An alternative:

You could reuse your good old html created by ruby if you insert in handlebars templates. But it's another js library...

http://www.handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Looks alot like mustache, but with some of the things I miss.  Not going to help me because I'd have to rewrite volumes of erb though, I was looking for a kinder gentler dry migration path.  Thanks though!

Comment: I doubt you'll fond betterbut kerp me informed